# Getting data from other calendar

Tags: vba, outlook

Hi i have written the below code to get the appointment from my outlook calendar. the code is working perfectly fine. However i also have another calendar (marked in green)  in my outlook & i want to get info from that calendar as well. can please someone modify my code so info from all the calendar

```
Sub meetingextract()
Dim application As Object: Set application = CreateObject("outlook.application")

dimmynamespace As outlook.Namespace

Dim tdystart As Date

Dim tyend As Date

Dim r As Long
Dim myappointments As outlook.items

Dim currentappointme As outlook.appointmentitem

Set mynamespace = application.getnamespace("mapi")
tdstart = Range("e1").Value


Dim myfol As outlook.folder

setmyfol = mynamespace.getdefaultfolder(olfoldercalener)

Range("a1:d1").Value = Array("subject", "from", "tillwhat", "location")

r = 2

tdyend = Range("f1").Value

Set myappointments = mynamespace.getdefaultfolder(olfoldercalendar).items
myappointments.Sort "[start]"

myappointments.includerecurrences = True

setcurrentappointment = myappointments.find("[start] >= """ & tdystart & """ and [start] <= """ & tdyend & """)

While TypeName(currentappointment) <> "nothing"

Cells(r, 1) = currentappointment.Subject

Cells(r, 2) = currentappointment.Start

Cells(r, 3) = currentappointment.End

Cells(r, 4) = currentappointment.Location

r = r + 1

Set currentappointment = myappointments.FindNext

Wend

End Sub
```

[image: Calender]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder).

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

Also you may check out the local folder structure and use the `Folders` property to get subfolders.